# I'm facing problem while installing axios using the command npm install axios in my terminal. … but not installing …

Tags: npm, axios

```
$ npm install axios
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\package.json'
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.13.12 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN User No description
npm WARN User No repository field.
npm WARN User No README data
npm WARN User No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fetch\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fetch\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ axios@0.21.1
updated 1 package and audited 2040 packages in 67.534s

135 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run `npm install axios` from the folder where is located your `package.json` file. Be sure to move in the root of your project before running npm install